# How to dynamically name a variable on an object in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, object

So, if I need to give a custom variable name to an object how would I do that?

For instance, if I have a gameID that is 12345 and its rating is 3 I want to save a variable called gameRatings_12345 thats value is 3 in my shared local object.

```
//share object
protected var mySavedData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("mySavedData");
```

I have the game id in a string

```
var gameID:String = "12345";
```

Then when I try to assign the value like this...

```
mySavedData.data.gameRatings_gameID = 3
```

I think it's literally reading it as `"mySavedData.data.gameRatings_gameID"` instead of `"mySavedData.data.gameRatings_12345"`

How can I give the variable a custom name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mySavedData.data["gameRatings_" + gameID]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [] notation for setting properties which are dynamically created at runtime.

In your example I think you'd use:

```
mySavedData.data["gameRatings_" + gameID] = 3;
```